# Weird bug animating with blender

Tags: animation, objects, snapping

I was trying to make a simulation with some spheres but every time I play the animation, it snaps to a single point.
[image]

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

https://www.mediafire.com/file/ec5hq5ecwnsbqmw/drgrdggrd.blend/file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Rigid Body world, Click on "delete all bakes", then run animation by pressing Spacebar again.

[image]

Comment: still didnt work, that was the first thing i tried, so thanks for trying to help!

Comment: did you try it it from your uploaded version? I tried it two times from the unchanged uploaded version - and it worked. What Blender version r u using?

Comment: yes and im using 3.0.1

Comment: you are totally right. I tried it out on 3.0 - worked. On 3.2 - worked. On 3.0.1 -> it didn't work. So i assume this is a bug.

Comment: Wait, i updated but it still does not work. Are you sure you only deleted the bakes and rebaked it?

Comment: i didn't rebake, i just deleted all bakes and hit spacebar to start the animation. That worked, but it didn't work with 3.01. Even with the newest 3.01 (downloaded just now) it didn't work.

Comment: Ah! that fixed my problem, great job! turns out rebaking it would mess up the animation. thanks!

Comment: not at all! Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is they all have the same location (even if you see them on different location)by selecting an object, pressing N to access the item pannel you can see his location is not 0, 0, 0, it can cause some issue.  [image]

you can simply hit F3 to access the quick search and look for apply -> all transform[image]

they will stay to the same location while having a location set to 0,0,0 and it will solve your issue.

The issue should come from the blender 3.0.1 version,
It worked fine on the 3.0.3

Comment: The issue still stands, now they all have the same orgin at a specific point and whenever I change their orgin to geometry it just does the bug again